# Relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined hidden symbol `__dso_handle' can not be used when making a shared object

Tags: python, c++, c, swig, ld

I want to use C++ functions in Python. Thus, I decided to try to use SWIG for that purpose.
At first, I run command:

```
swig -python test.i
```

Then compile it with g++-6.2 as follows:

```
g++-6.2 -c test.cpp test_wrap.c -fPIC -I /usr/include/python3.6m
```

To this moment everything works fine, but the problem occurs at the last step when linking must be created. I run command :

```
ld -shared test.o test_wrap.o -o _test.so
```

As suggested in [Swig tutorial](http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html), but I recieve a following error:

```
test.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
test.cpp:(.text+0x66): undefined reference to `__dso_handle'
ld: test.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined hidden symbol `__dso_handle' can not be used when making a shared object
ld: final link failed: Bad value
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Seems like vDSO library is missed during linkage.

Answer (score 6):

You don't link with the `ld` command. You link with the same `$(CC)` or `$(CXX)` (`gcc` or `g++`) you compile with, using options appropriate for linking. It will drive the backend linker `ld` with the right command line options for the ABI, target format, etc. that should be generated.

Do this and it should work fine:

```
g++-6.2 -shared test.o test_wrap.o -o _test.so
```