# relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol `stdout@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a PIE object

Tags: c, linux, assembly, gcc, linker

### The problem

I'm currently reading [this book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4842-7437-8) and with the chapter about dynamic linking with the following code:

`link_example.s`

```
.globl main

.section .data

output:
    .ascii "Yeet\n\0"

.section .text
main:
    enter $0, $0
    movq stdout, %rdi
    movq $output, %rsi
    call fprintf

    movq $0, %rax
    leave
    ret
```

Now according to the book, I need to compile it as follows to link the C-library dynamically:

```
gcc -rdynamic link_example.s -o link_example
```

But I'm getting the following error message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cchUlvqS.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol `stdout@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: failed to set dynamic section sizes: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am I doing wrong?

### What have you tried?

#### Adding `-fPIE` flag

I tried what the compiler suggested by adding the `-fPIE` flag:

```
gcc -rdynamic -fPIE link_example.s -o link_example
```

but I'm still getting the same error again.

#### Searching similar posts

I found a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57957080/relocation-r-x86-64-pc32-against-undefined-hidden-symbol-dso-handle-can-not) which said, that I just need to use the `-shared` flag:

```
gcc -shared link_example.s -o link_example
```

but this gives me:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccxktZan.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol `stdout@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: failed to set dynamic section sizes: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

and if I add the `-fPIC` flag:

```
gcc -shared -fPIC link_example.s -o link_example
```

then I'm getting this:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccKIQ9sl.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol `stdout@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: failed to set dynamic section sizes: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: You actually need to add `-no-pie` (or rewrite the code to be PIC).

Comment: Oh, it's working now. Thank you! Could you please write your comment as an answer please so I can tick this question as answered @Jester ? I'd be also happy to get some details why I need this flag and not `-rdynamic`, because according to `man gcc` about `-no-pie`: `Don't produce a dynamically linked position independent executable.` What is it exactly doing here? This sounds like as it would disable dynamic linking.

Comment: @TornaxO7 PIE means that the main binary (and not just shared libraries) is position independent.  This hardens the code against certain attacks but also requires special assembly programming techniques to work.  `-fpie` instructs the compiler to generate such code, but if you write in assembly you have to do so yourself.  `-no-pie` turns off PIE, permitting you to write conventional position-dependent code in your main binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me show you how to fix up the assembly language from your book so it works with your compiler's default settings.

As the comments on the question say, the problem is that your compiler defaults to generating *position-independent executables*.  This means the addresses of `stdout`, `fprintf`, and `output` are not known at link time, so the linker is unable to "relocate" the instructions that refer to them.

What *is* known at link time, however, is the *offsets between the addresses of these things and the program counter*.  That means, if you just write the assembly a little differently, it will work.  Like this:

```
.globl main

.section .data

output:
    .ascii "Yeet\n\0"

.section .text
main:
    enter $0, $0
    movq stdout(%rip), %rdi
    leaq output(%rip), %rsi
    call fprintf@PLT

    movq $0, %rax
    leave
    ret
```

Notice that the change is a little different for all three. `mov stdout, %rdi` becomes `mov stdout(%rip), %rdi` -- just a different addressing mode for the same instruction.  Loading from memory at the fixed address `stdout` becomes loading from memory at the fixed *displacement* `stdout` from the RIP register (aka the program counter).  Loading *the fixed address* `output` with `mov $output, %rsi`, on the other hand, becomes `lea output(%rip), %rsi`.  I would suggest you think of this one as *always having been* a load-effective-address operation, but the old code, with the executable at a fixed address, was able to express that operation with move-immediate instead of an actual lea instruction.  Finally, `call fprintf` becomes `call fprintf@PLT`.  This is telling the linker that the call needs to go through the *procedure linkage table* -- your book should explain what this is and why it's needed.

Incidentally, I see several other problems with this assembly language, of which the most important are:

- The string `"Yeet\n\0"` belongs in the *read-only* data section.
- The x86-64 ABI says that variadic functions like `fprintf` need to be told the number of floating point arguments they are receiving, by setting `eax` appropriately.
- `enter` and `leave` are unnecessary on x86-64.  (Also, `enter` is a painfully slow microcoded instruction that shouldn't be used at all.)

I would have written something like this instead:

```
    .section .rodata, "a", @progbits
.output:
    .string "Yeet\n"

    .section .text, "ax", @progbits
    .globl main
    .type  main, @function
main:
    sub    $8, %rsp
    mov    stdout(%rip), %rdi
    lea    .output(%rip), %rsi
    xor    %eax, %eax
    call   fprintf@PLT
    xor    %eax, %eax
    add    $8, %rsp
    ret
```

(You need to subtract 8 from `%rsp` at the beginning of the function, and add it back afterward, because the ABI says that `%rsp` must always be a multiple of 16 *at the point of a `call` instruction* -- which means that it's *not* a multiple of 16 on entry to any function, but instead `%rsp` mod 16 is 8, because `call` pushes eight bytes (the return address).  You were getting this for free as a side effect of the `enter` and `leave`, but take those out and you have to do it by hand.)